# More efficient way to round to day timestamps using pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have imported some timestamps into a **Pandas** frame (via **MongoDBclient**). They are to the microseconds. I'd like a way to round to the Day. I've seen a previous question about using `np.round` while converting to ints and back again, but this doesn't work (I tried inlining a div by 3600 x 24 x 100000 but that didn't work).

I have this rather plain version, but it seems REALLY inefficient. What am I missing in either `to_datetime`, or the `np.round` example.

```
df['doa'] = df['doa'].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
pd.to_datetime(df['doa'])
```

Note, these are not INDEXES so I can't use the frequency trick.

Answer (score 0):

There's this feature request, which suggests there's no good way:
[ENH: add rounding method to DatetimeIndex/TimedeltaIndex](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4314)

However, in the article I found there is also this approach for minutes, which I might be able to modify:

pd.DatetimeIndex(((dti.asi8/(1e9*60)).round()*1e9*60).astype(np.int64))

[Rounding Pandas Timestamp to minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031169/rounding-pandas-timestamp-to-minutes)