# using the timedelta.round() function

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, python-datetime

I've seen multiple questions asked on how to define your own function that does things similar to this, but I can't figure out how to use timedelta's built in function. Does anyone have an example of a use of timedelta.round()? I have timedelta objects that I want to round to the closest full-day.

Documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.round.html is:

> Timedelta.round
>
> Round the Timedelta to the specified resolution
>
> Parameters:
>
> freq : a freq string indicating the rounding resolution
>
> Returns:   a new Timedelta rounded to the given resolution of `freq`
>
> Raises:    ValueError if the freq cannot be converted

Comment: Thank you for your question and the answer. I was also looking for this.

Could you also format your question probably, please?

Answer (score 11):

This question is already answered, but I put it a MWE in for better understanding:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series(pd.to_timedelta([
        '0 days +01:01:02.123',
        '0 days +04:03:04.651']))
df.dt.round('5s')  #Rounds to 5sec
```

Output would be:

```
0   01:01:00
1   04:03:05
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Other useful and connected question (timedelta is similar in usage to datetime):

- [How do I round datetime column to nearest quarter hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344533/how-do-i-round-datetime-column-to-nearest-quarter-hour)
- [Rounding Pandas Timestamp to minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031169/rounding-pandas-timestamp-to-minutes)

Answer (score 5):

I've answered my own question. The solution was just the string 'd' as a parameter, whereas I was trying 'day','days', etc. Hope this helps someone in need.

Comment: Thank you! the `d` part saved my day :D